# Equivalent of datenum in R programming

Tags: r

I have previous experience of matlab but very new to R. The basic problem that I am having is like this -

I have a data which has 10 columns. The first 6 columns correspond to year, month, day, hour min and secs.

```
E.g data_example = 
2013 6 15 11 15 0 ...
2013 6 15 11 20 0 ...
2013 6 15 11 25 0 ...
```

In matlab for dealing with dates as numbers I used to easily compute that using [datenum(data_example(:,1:6))](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html)

but in R what is the best way to go about getting similar numerical representation of the 6 columns.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data and show us what the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternatives. They all make use of `ISOdatetime` :

**1)** Assuming `DF` is your data frame try `ISOdatetime` like this:

```
DF$datetime <- ISOdatetime(DF[[1]], DF[[2]], DF[[3]], DF[[4]], DF[[5]], DF[[6]])
```

**2)** or like this:

```
DF$datetime <- do.call(ISOdatetime, setNames(as.list(DF[1:6]), NULL))
```

**3a)** If this is a time series suitable for zoo (distinct times and all numeric) then we could use `read.zoo` in the zoo package together with `ISOdatetime` like this:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 1:6, FUN = ISOdatetime)
```

**3b)** or using `read.zoo` to read from a file or character string (latter shown here):

```
# sample input lines
Lines <- "2013 6 15 11 15 0  1
2013 6 15 11 20 0 2
2013 6 15 11 25 0 3
"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:6, FUN = ISOdatetime)
```

which gives this zoo series:

```
> z
2013-06-15 11:15:00 2013-06-15 11:20:00 2013-06-15 11:25:00 
                  1                   2                   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parse_date_time` function from the Lubridate package.

```
x <- paste0(data_example[,1:6])
x <- parse_date_time(x,"%y%m%d %H%M")
```

More information in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)

**EDIT** 
@joran told me to test it, and it didn't work, so I made some modifications:

```
data_example = data.frame(t(c(13,2,9,14,30)))
x <- paste0(data_example[,1:3],collapse="-")
y <- paste0(data_example[,4:5],collapse=":")
xy<- paste(x,y)
xy <- parse_date_time(xy,"%y%m%d %H%M")
xy
# "2013-02-09 14:30:00 UTC"
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way to do it

Comment: I think you mixed in some matlab syntax there with `data_example(:,1:6)`.

Comment: That's at least R code, but I don't think it will do what you think it will. Try it out on a small sample data frame.

Answer (score 0):

The units of the returned value are a bit different in R than in Matlab (see comment in code).  Also, since you have other columns in your data frame, you will first need to subset the data frame to contain only the relevant (6) date columns, then add them back to the data frame as a new column at the end.

```
test <- data.frame("year"=c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2001, 1970)
                   , "month"=c(6,6, 6, 4, 1)
                   , "day"=c(15,15, 15, 19, 1)
                   , "hour"=c(11,11, 11, 11, 0)
                   , "min"=c(15,20, 25, 30, 0)
                   , "second"=c(0,0, 0 ,0, 0))
# pad to the right # of digits
dates00 <- apply(test, c(1,2), sprintf, fmt="%02s") 
# combine the date components in each row into a single string
dates0 <- apply(dates00, 1, paste, collapse=" ") 
#format to a date object
dates <- as.POSIXct(dates0, format="%Y %m %d %H %M %S") 
# numbers are seconds since "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"; according 
# to the help file for daynum, Matlab returns the number (from 
# daynum) as fractional days since "January 0, 0000"
as.numeric(dates)
```